# Understanding potential energy (2)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

I know that several questions on this topic and one with even the same name exists, but I don't think they fully answer my questions. I request you to first hear me out, and then point out any possible duplicates

If I understand this correctly, potential energy is simply potential work "stored"(?) inside a system of $2$ or more bodies, and for all cases I have come across, only the change in potential energy, equal to negative of the work done, has mattered. I have two doubts though:

**1) Why is potential energy for different systems pre-defined at specific values?**

G.P.E is defined as $0$ at infinity, Elastic P.e as $0$ at the mean position and so on. Is this a completely arbitrary decision, or does it *have to be* defined this way to be consistent with the rest of classical physics,like gravitational constant being *$\mathrm{6.67 \times 10^{-11}\ m^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2}}$*  so that the units work.

**2) Is there any limit to the "change in potential energy" of a system?**

change in g.p.e, for example, seems to have infinite range. Whats the point of law of conservation of energy then, If I can extract out as much work as I want?

Comment: How can u extract as much  work as u want ?

Comment: The change in potential energy is negative of the work done. So Ideally, I should be able to extract As much work as I want by “changing” the configuration of the system and thus the potential energy sufficiently, shouldn’t I? If I am at an infinite distance from a point mass, wont the change in k.e, ideally, be inifnity as the distance goes to 0?

Comment: Change in PE = -work done by conservative forces.And suppose if ur changing the configuration of system such that their $\Delta PE$ = infinity.Then you need to do  work on the system , which means you must do infinite amount of work .I don't see how r u extracting work ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Why is potential energy for different systems pre-defined at specific
> values?**

It is just a conventional choice. Since what you can actually measure are  *differences* of energy, energy is always defined within an arbitrary constant.

In the two-body Newtonian gravitational problem, usually potential energy is chosen to be zero at infinite separation of the bodies. However this is not necessary and any finite value at infinite distance would provide the same physical description. However, it is interesting to notice that if one takes the limiting situation of small changes of distances (like the case of bodies not departing too much from the surface of a planet) a linear approximation to the general expression is well justified:
$$
\Delta U = - \frac{GmM}{(R+h)} +  \frac{GmM}{R} \simeq \frac{GmM}{R^2}h = m g h
$$
where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration at the planet surface. It is clear that this expression of the gravitational potential energy is using the distance $R$ from the center of mass of the planet of mass M as a new zero of the potential energy.

Another example is an atomic system. Let's make the case of two Hydrogen atoms. If we take the potential energy of the two atoms at infinite distance equal to zero the potential energy at distance $R$ would correspond to the work done by the interatomic forces in connection to a displacement from $R$ to infinity.
However, the same system can be seen as made by two nuclei and two electrons. In this case one could choose to assign to the $R=\infty$ atomic configuration the sum of the energy of two isolated hydrogens in their individual $1s$ ground states ($2 \times -13.6$ eV). With such a choice, the value of potential energy includes the energy necessary to get the two ground state configurations of the atoms.

As you see, the conventional character of the choice can be exploited in different ways.

> **Is there any limit to the "change in potential energy" of a system?**

Not really. It depends on the form of the potential energy as a function of its variables. Of course, every potential energy depends on some model for forces and the model could have some limit of validity. For example, an ideal spring has a potential energy $\frac12 k x^2$ which can grow without limits when $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. Of course, every real spring will go out of the validity of Hooke's law beyond some finite elongation and eventually will break in pieces. Nevertheless, within the model, the potential energy is not upper bounded.